# Does INSERT OVERWRITE create new empty partition if SELECT returns 0 rows

Tags: hive

Lets say we have a table partitioned on some column col.

Assume that the partition col='abc' doesn't already exist.

We try to insert rows:-

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE MyTable PARTITION(col='abc')
SELECT 
.
.
.
```

Now what if the SELECT returns 0 rows. Will this still create a partition col='abc' as empty partition (empty because that partition will not contain any data). In short -- will it create a folder col='abc' with no files under it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will create empty partition even if `SELECT` returned 0 results. To understand if the partition was created you can check that task was finished successfully and run `SELECT` part again and check if it returns no data.